# Matlab add variable to stack

Tags: matlab, variables, stack

I am beginner in Matlab and I have not time for learning it. So I have next question.

I work with string data type like `x = 2; y = 3; z = x + y;`. I need to declare some variables and work with them. Can I add variables to stack? Can I write function like

```
function addVar(name, value) {
    stack[name] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cell arrays:

```
data{1} = 'x = 2';
data{2} = 'y = 3';
data{3} = 'z = x+y'
```

This will generate

```
>> data    
data = 

    'x = 2'    'y = 3'    'z = x+y'
```

and then you can use it, for example, like this:

```
>> for k = 1:length(data), eval(data{k}), end
x =
     2

y =
     3

z =
     5
```

Comment: Oh, if function EVAL can calculate "z" that it work with stack of variables. It's very nice!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try struct:

```
>> s = struct;
>> s.a = 'a string';
>> s.b = 3;
>> s.c = zeros(5);
>> s

s = 

    a: 'a string'
    b: 3
    c: [5x5 double]
```

But in general, Matlab doesn't require variables declaration. Here there are more details:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/31248-variable-declaration-in-matlab

Comment: I need some var like hash-table. When function get string "z = x + y"  try replace "x" and "y" with values from hash-table and calculate "z".